# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime,When importing from XMl element

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to extract Date time from the following XML element:

```
<PageSaved type="Date">10/19/2010 11:09:36 AM</PageSaved>
```

I have written the following code in C#, but I am getting an exception stating that the string was not recognized as a valid date time.

```
foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes){
    if (child.Name == Importer_Constants.PageSaved){
        PageSaved.Append( HttpUtility.HtmlDecode( child.InnerText.Trim() ) );
    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to parse the date like this:

```
PageSaved.Append(DateTime.ParseExact(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(child.InnerText.Trim()), "dd/MM/yyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: I was a bit to quick - I've corrected it now - thanks for the headsup!

Comment: yeh..Above code gives the same error for string like HTmlDecode has some invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PageSaved.Append(DateTime.ParseExact(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(child.InnerText.Trim()), "dd/MM/yyy h:mm:ss tt", null));
```

Comment: Its not working.So please give me another solution if u have any.